# submit data from one rails application to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-migration

I have two rails applications. I would like to submit data from one application to another but I want it go through the controller logic as it's not just a DB dumb. I tried using directory HTTP call with POST but it didn't work as it asked for Authenticity Token.

Now that I own both apps what is the easiest way in your opinion to do this?

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [ActionWebService](http://aws.rubyonrails.org/) for that purpose. Build the server in one app and the client in the other.

Comment: I also figured I could use plain REST web services too